# How can I identify user when user reload the page

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io

I'm creating a card game like crazy8. And I already publish prototype.

Look here http://himapoyo.com

My problem is, when I reload the page during the game, socket is disconnected and my socket.id is changed.

So server side program can't identify me. Now, server remove player from table when socket is disconnected.(because if server don't remove the player who server can't identify, game is stopped, so I program). But if I can identify user, I don't want to remove player who just reload the page from table.

QUESTION: how can I identify user when user reload the page?

I think using cookie as ID is best for this problem. Are there Other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Other options would include:

- Using local storage on the client
- Passing query string values in the url
- Posting the user id as part as the refresh
- Storing the user in a server side session
- Storing user information in redis cache.

I'm sure there are many more but this should be enough

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) that once a user refreshes the page (reconnects his socket) the socket ID changes (obviously) and you can't identify the user.

First of all, you shouldn't keep track of user using his socket ID as the socket ID will change every time the user reconnects. You should keep track of the socket ID for communication with the user AFTER you have identified the user.

So, what I would do is make an "authenticate" event on the server side and disconnect those sockets who don't emit the "authenticate" event. This event can expect any form of credentials (JWT, username:password etc).

After the user has been authenticated, you can take that socket ID and map that to the user ID and use the socket ID for further communication.

So the server side flow will be like this:

```
io.on("connect", function (socket) {
    socket.on("authenticate", function(data) {
         // do auth and then make other events

         // if auth

         socket.auth = true;
         socket.emit("message", "User authenticated");
    });

    // If socket fails to authenticate within 3 seconds after connect, disconnect it

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!socket.auth) {
            socket.disconnect();
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

After going to your app, I found that there is no authentication required. This should not be the case as I can highjack any user's slot at the table by just sending his/her name.

If you are okay with that then perhaps you can just keep track of the user name and map it to socket ID on connect.